# Ansible how to copy to destination folder which has dynamic suffix

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I need to copy content of a local source folder to remote folder, where source contents are as follows:

```
files/
├── certs
    ├── server.crt
    └── server.key
```

The destination path will vary with its suffix. For example if the destination path is `claim-pvc-3b6165b0-f1d6-11ea-a39b-0050569b0faf/` . Here `claim-pvc-` always remains constant but its suffix `3b6165b0-f1d6-11ea-a39b-0050569b0faf` would change.

I have tried using the following , but it did not work:

```
- name: copy contents
  copy:
    dest: "claim-pvc-*"
    src: files/certs/
```

Please help me with this, am a beginner in ansible.

**UPDATE**

As suggested in comment. I have tried to use find module to get the full name of the directory:

```
- name: find the
  find:
    paths: "/mnt/k8sMount/"
    patterns: "claim-pvc"
    file_type: "directory"
  register: find_result

- name: print find_result
  debug: var=find_result
```

But could not get the directory name. This was the result

```
ok: [master] => {
    "find_result": {
        "changed": false,
        "examined": 28,
        "failed": false,
        "files": [],
        "matched": 0,
        "msg": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use the `find` module on the parent directory of the `dest` dir to determine the actual name of the dest dir, and then use it in the `copy` task.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, i have tried it but could not get the desired output, I have updated the question with observations. Please let me know if any mistakes.

Comment: you should check the "examples" at [http://ansible.is.org/modules/find_module.html](http://ansible.is.org/modules/find_module.html) for what`patterns` you need to supply